# finding hash code of the image using MD5 algorithm and after downloading the same image from the browser again generate the same hash code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on document authentication project. This is a asp.net C# webform project. Firstly I upload the image and do some process on it. I added the QRCode on the image like adding the watermark after that find the hash code of a image using md5 algorithm and save the image with QRCode in folder and also database. After that I download the same image with QRCode that I already uploaded and again find the hash code of the image and I got different hash code.
Now what I need to do, to get the same hash code of the image?

UploadDocument.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using QRCoder;

public partial class User_UploadDocument : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    string id;
    string name;
    string email;
    string photo;
    BasicCode b = new BasicCode();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fudoc.HasFile)
        {
            using (Stream stream = fudoc.PostedFile.InputStream)
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = ReadFully(stream); // Get the byte array of the uploaded file

                // Generate hash code for the uploaded image
                string uploadedHash = ComputeFileHash(fileBytes);

                // Your existing code for processing the uploaded file and storing the hash code
                con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LIS"]);
                cmd = new SqlCommand();
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "Select id, name, email, photo From Registration where id=@id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Session["id"]);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    id = dr["id"].ToString();
                    name = dr["name"].ToString();
                    email = dr["email"].ToString();
                    photo = dr["photo"].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();


                DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Today;
                string date = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

                con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LIS"]);
                cmd = new SqlCommand();
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = @"Insert Into Documents (did,id,document_type,doc_name_original,doc_name_qr,doc_with_qr_hashcode,qr_code,date)
                                    Values (@did, @id, @dt, @dno, @dnq, @dwqhc, @qr, @date)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@did", b.generateID("did", "Documents"));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", txtdocumentname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTime.Date);

                // Generate QR code
                string qrData = $"{txtdocumentname.Text}\n{name}\n{email}\n{photo}";
                QRCodeGenerator qr = new QRCodeGenerator();
                QRCodeData data = qr.CreateQrCode(qrData, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
                QRCode code = new QRCode(data);

                // Convert QR code to a bitmap
                Bitmap bmp = code.GetGraphic(5);

                // Save QR code image
                string qrimgname = "QRCode_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".png";
                string qrpath = Server.MapPath("QR_Code/") + qrimgname;
                bmp.Save(qrpath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                // Here We will upload image with QR code
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(fudoc.PostedFile.FileName);
                System.Drawing.Image upImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fudoc.PostedFile.InputStream);

                // Draw QR code onto the uploaded image
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(upImage))
                {
                    // Draw QR code onto the uploaded image at specified coordinates
                    g.DrawImage(bmp, new PointF(0, 0));
                    upImage.Save(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("ImageWithQR"), fileName));
                }

                // Compute MD5 hash of the image
                byte[] imageBytes;
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    upImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }

                using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
                {
                    byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(imageBytes);

                    // Convert byte array to hex string (hash code)
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
                    {
                        sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2")); // "x2" means lowercase hexadecimal
                    }

                    // Store the hash code in the database parameter
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dwqhc", sb.ToString());
                }

                // Doc Original Name
                string Afileextention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fudoc.FileName);
                string aname = "Document-" + b.generateID("did", "Documents") + Afileextention;
                string axpath = Server.MapPath("Documents/") + aname;
                fudoc.SaveAs(axpath);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dno", aname);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dnq", fileName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qr", qrimgname);
                cmd.Connection = con;

                int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                if (n > 0)
                {
                    string script = @"<script>
                                Swal.fire({
                                  title: 'Your Document Uploaded Successfully!',
                                  text: 'click ok button to continue!',
                                  icon: 'success'
                                });
                             </script>";

                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowAlert", script, false);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string script = @"<script>
                                Swal.fire({
                                  title: 'Please Upload the file!',
                                  text: 'click ok button to continue!',
                                  icon: 'error'
                                });
                             </script>";

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowAlert", script, false);
        }
    }

    // Method to compute hash code of a file
    private string ComputeFileHash(byte[] data)
    {
        using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(data);

            // Convert byte array to hex string
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2")); // "x2" means lowercase hexadecimal
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    // Method to read stream into a byte array
    private byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
`
```

AuthenticateDocument.aspx.cs

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class User_AuthenticateDocument : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnupload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fudoc.HasFile)
        {
            using (Stream stream = fudoc.PostedFile.InputStream)
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = ReadFully(stream); // Get the byte array of the uploaded file

                // Generate hash code for the uploaded image
                string uploadedHash = ComputeFileHash(fileBytes);

                // Check if the hash code exists in the database
                if (HashExistsInDatabase(uploadedHash))
                {
                    string script = @"<script>
                                    Swal.fire({
                                      title: 'Your Document is Authenticate!',
                                      text: 'click ok button to continue!',
                                      icon: 'success'
                                    });
                                 </script>";

                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowAlert", script, false);
                }
                else
                {
                    string script = @"<script>
                                    Swal.fire({
                                      title: 'Your Document is not Authenticate!',
                                      text: 'click ok button to continue!',
                                      icon: 'error'
                                    });
                                 </script>";

                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowAlert", script, false);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string script = @"<script>
                                Swal.fire({
                                  title: 'Please Upload the file!',
                                  text: 'click ok button to continue!',
                                  icon: 'error'
                                });
                             </script>";

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ShowAlert", script, false);
        }
    }

    // Method to read fully from a stream and convert to byte array
    private byte[] ReadFully(Stream input)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    // Method to compute hash code of a file from byte array
    private string ComputeFileHash(byte[] data)
    {
        using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
        {
            byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(data);

            // Convert byte array to hex string
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2")); // "x2" means lowercase hexadecimal
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    // Method to check if hash code exists in the database
    private bool HashExistsInDatabase(string uploadedHash)
    {
        using (con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LIS"]))
        {
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Documents WHERE doc_with_qr_hashcode = @HashCode";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HashCode", uploadedHash);
                int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                return count > 0;
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

when i download the same image from browser i need the same hash code that i find previously.

Comment: Create a test case that creates a hash and checks the hash without all the other steps.  The isolate where the issue is located.  You are doing the following 1) Generate Hash 2) Sending data across connection (upload) 3) Processing 4) Downloading 5) Check Hash.  Which step is causing issue?   You need to find out where the error is occurring.  That is not our job.